# Привет всем.Нужна помощь с задачей на С

Tags: c, файлы, файловая-система

Вот условие: Напишите программу, которая добавляет слова в файл и сделайте так, чтобы каждое слово было пронумеровано порядке его в соответствии с добавление в список, начиная с 1 Позаботьтесь о том, чтобы при втором запуске программы новая нумерация слов начиналась с того места, где была закончена нумерация при предыдущем запуске.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 256

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    char theName[] = "dist_zavd.txt";
    int a,n, g = 0, nW=0, words = 0;
    char *p[LEN];
    char tmp;
    f = fopen(theName, "w");
    while (g != 10)
    {
        printf("Enter words: ");
        fgets(p,20,stdin);
        if (a = strtok(p," ")){
            ++nW;
            printf("\nquantity words = %d\n", nW, p);
        }
        g++;
    }
    printf("\nquantity words = %d, words=%c\n",nW,p);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос? проверить, работает ли Ваш код? Или рассказать, где он падает? Или рассказать, что `char *p[LEN]` не то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: Я хотел би чтоби мне сказали где именно ошибка в моем коде,и как ее решить,то есть чтоби помогли мне написать саму фуецию которая 
выполнит все требование задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, наверное.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 256

int main(void) {
    FILE *f;
    char theName[] = "dist_zavd.txt";
    int n, g = 0, nW=0, words = 0;
    char p[LEN];
    char *word;
    f = fopen(theName, "w");

    printf("Enter words: ");
    fgets(p,LEN,stdin);
    word = strtok(p," ");
    while(word != NULL)
    {
        ++nW;
        printf("%d. %s\n", nW, word);
        word = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    printf("\nquantity words = %d", nW);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ляя,чувак спс..